# Error "dup key: { : null }" mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo un schema de mongoose de esta forma:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const thingsSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        required: true,
        unique: false,
        type: String,
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', thingsSchema);
```

al intentar insertar un nuevo documento me da este error:

```
"E11000 duplicate key error index: thingsSchema.$userId_1  dup key: { : null }"
```

ese error lo que indica es que userId es unico, y lo voy a insertar duplicado ya que si se ha insertado antes, pero como pueden ver yo especifico `unique: false`. La question es que antes lo tenia `unique: true`, por lo que si se crearon algunos con diversos `userId`, pero luego al cambiar para que no fueran unicos me seguia dando ese error, incluso despues de borrar los elementos de la base de dato.
Incluso si removia el campo userId seguia dando ese error, que es el que mostre anteriormente, que como se puede ver `{ :null }` indica que se esta intentando crear con valor `null`.
Llevo usando `mongoose` y `mongodb` un buen tiempo, y nunca habia tenido este error. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: haz probado reiniciar el servidor de base de datos?

Comment: si, sigue igual, intentare borrar todos los datos, y insertar los documentos de nuevo, esta vez bien, aunque esto no seria la solucion practica a mi pregunta.

Comment: es una solucion nuclear, pero puedes desinstalar mongodb y borrar las configuraciones (no la base de datos) y volverlo a instalar

Comment: Revisa que no haya ningún documento con el userId a null

Comment: @pablo No, no hay. Incluso borraba todos los users, y al crear 2 con el mismo `userId` daba este error. Extrano. Solucione este problema borrando la BD, el problema era local asi que no me preocupaba la perdida de datos. Ya no me da ese error, pero deje de cambiarle el `unique`

Comment: Elimina la collection y la vuelves a recrear. Es problema de indice que genera mongoDB

Comment: No controlo mucho de esto, pero si le pones requerido = true y luego quieres añadir uno con valor null eso no debería fallar?

Comment: y sabes por que pasa eso?