# Como limpiar la base de dato de mongodb en debian

Tags: mongodb, debian

Por algun motivo mi base de dato de mongodb esta corrupta (no se comporta como deberia [Error "dup key: { : null }" mongodb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76445/error-dup-key-null-mongodb)), y quisiera limpiarla, borrar todos sus datos completamente. Estoy en Debian y no se cual sea la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo. Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En linux puedes usar el comando:

```
mongo <dbname> --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

donde `dbname` es el nombre de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Tambien pueden escribir `mongo` en la consola. `use myDataBase` siendo `myDataBase` el nombre de la base de datos. Luego `db.dropDataBase()` para borrarla. Para ver las bases de datos prueben `show dbs`. Todo esto luego de estar en el shell de mongo.